# Location update stops after reboot application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, location, cllocationmanager

Location update stops tracking after some longer period of time (few days) or after restart device. Is there any solution for this problem?

I have set "App registers for location updates" in plist file.

Comment: No, only VOIP apps will be restarted by the OS after a reboot.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same thing with mix of location updates and voip. When device rebooted and app get launch there is no location updates although I see the app in the multitasking and the location icon.

Answer (score 0):

[According](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) to the official Apple iOS SDK automatic stating for an app is only possible for apps that declare the `VOIP` background mode:

> **VOIP**
>
> The app provides Voice-over-IP services. Apps with this key are
>   automatically launched after system boot so that the app can
>   reestablish VoIP services. Apps with this key are also allowed to play
>   background audio.

No other background mode specifies that the app will launched after system boot.

If you use the `VOIP` key and you app is not a real VOIP app you might be rejected so this might not be an option.

Comment: Ok, so what's the solution, I just want to keep my app tracking user's location for a long period of time and periodically update server with location info?

Comment: Well your app will be able to run in the background, but if the user restarts his/hers device your app will not automatically be launched. If you app gets killed because of memory issues then you should make sure that you release as many memory as you can on receiving a memory warning.

Comment: @Bojan If the user terminates the app, then there is no, and there should be no solution that your app continues working. The app shall be to the benefit of the user, not to your benefit.

Comment: Of course if user kill the app, but problem is app stays inactive after reboot, but location update is not working anymore after that. My question is why and how to relaunch location update?

Comment: @Bojan according to the Apple documentation you can't relaunch for location updates.